# How to Check the cell from excel which has formula using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

I Want to access the cell which has formula from the excel workbook.Actually my python script is working fine only to read the data from excel, but i need that only the cell which has formula and to print that cells only
An example would be really appreciated..........

Answer (score 0):

Two things that could help you solve the problem:

1. There's a typo: `HasForumla` instead of `HasFormula`
2. `e` is a string, not a `cell` object, so `e.HasFormula` won't work.

You probably want to use

```
e = sheet.cell(row,17)
```

to access the `Cell` object at that position. I'm not sure where you got your `HasFormula` attribute from, though - couldn't find it in the docs.

**Edit:**
I just looked at the README for the current distribution where it's stated that

> `xlrd` will safely and reliably ignore any of these if present in the
>   file:
>
> - [...]
> - Formulas (results of formula calculations are extracted, of course).
> - [...]

Comment: Can u give tell me the code which the cell has formula or not to check.... Thank u. Is there any other way to check the cell has formula or not

Comment: @Raj: It seems that `xlrd` can't do this. I don't have it installed, so I can't check. Where did you get your `HasFormula` attribute? Or was that just a guess?

Comment: Then. in which i can do ., should u modify the code and paste here.  Tim Pietzcker. thank u  advance

Comment: @TimPietzcker, as you mentioned here, the row with empty data with formulas should not be counted. But now I encountered the issue that it actually be counted.  See my issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421025/xlrd-ignore-rows-with-formula